# Why is StringLength not validated when using ValidationContext outside of MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a data entry page in my MVC application and have defined data annotations for validating the input.  This works as expected.

I also have a file upload that needs to validate the incoming data with the same rules, so instead of writing the rules again, I decided to map each row into an instance of the model class so I could use the same validation rules outside of a controller (described in other SO answers.)

The [Required] attribute works, but the others I use, StringLength and Range, do not.  Here's a sample that I tested in LinqPad with the same result:

```
void Main()
{
    var model = new Model { Name = "Test String" };
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
    Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, validationResults);
    validationResults.Select(w => w.ErrorMessage).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Model
{
    [Required, StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "String length is outside of range.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would expect the StringLength to cause a validation error since it is greater than the max length of 8, but it does not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add one more parameter:

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, validationResults, true);
```

Without that, it validates only for "Required".

[MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_Validator_TryValidateObject_System_Object_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationContext_System_Collections_Generic_ICollection_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationResult__System_Boolean_)

> `validateAllProperties` Boolean
>
> `true` to validate all properties; if `false`, only required attributes are validated

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you for the quick, concise, and correct answer!